# What is the bigger number of particles crossing an area: the number of photons or the number of neutrinos?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photons, astrophysics, neutrinos, stellar-physics

Take an squared area with (10²)² m² in front of the sun. What is the bigger number of particles crossing an area: the number of photons or the number of neutrinos?

Just for clarification: you can calculate the values on earth, if you want (you'd need a distance to be able to calculate). You can use simplifications if they are needed and justified. If my area is limiting the wavelength you can as well make the math with an arbitrary (but a completely detailed and specified area in that case).

And make sure to put some sources of the data you've taken.

I'm asking this question after coming across the upper bound of the photon mass.

Comment: There are far more photons than neutrinos. That should be obvious from the peaks of their spectra.

Comment: Estimates for both quantities can be found in Mukhanov's book on cosmology.

Comment: @Danu Which book? Physical foundations of cosmology? And thanks for giving a helpful answer.

Comment: @Vendetta That is indeed Mukhanov's (only) book on cosmology.

Comment: Wait! I know this one, is it $7 \times 10^{10} neutrinos\:\mathrm{ cm^{-2} s^{-1}}$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino#Observed_data

Comment: @Gert Thanks for your answer. Now I have to find out how to separate the solar contribution from the rest of the universe's contribution. Probably the energy will be useful for that. I do not know particle physics (I only saw lectures here and there), so I'm trying to learn a thing or two with this question (which apparently is a little discouraged here, as people downvote as a principle what they call homework questions, regardless of your level of knowledge).

Comment: @Vendetta: just look up how much energy the earth receives per unit of time, then divide by the energy of an average VIS photon.

Comment: Are you looking for *just* solar photons and solar neutrinos, or *all* photons and all neutrinos, or something else?

Comment: @ChrisWhite For all of both particles. But I do want to know the proportion of those numbers to the sun quantities. I imagine that the sun accounts for almost all of photon radiation in the visible wavelengths, as we can't see most stars under daylight (certainly such observation is not something I'd expect at all wavelengths). I'll have to look up for some kind of place with all possible neutrino releasing mechanisms. I know they could be produced while the Big Bang happened, inside stars and in nuclear decay, and also in other physical contexts that are more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

That the numbers of photons far, far outweighs the number of neutrinos can also be determined as follows.

One of the main contributors of energy production in the Sun's core is the [proton-proton chain reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_core#Proton-proton_chain_reaction), which produces one neutrino and about $26.7\:\mathrm{MeV}$ of energy per helium atom produced. This colossal amount of energy is gradually partitioned into smaller and smaller packets as it diffuses from the core to the surface of the Sun, which it leaves mainly as visible light photons.

The energy of an average VIS light photon however is only about $1.5\:\mathrm{eV}$, so millions of times smaller than  $26.7\:\mathrm{MeV}$, ergo the number of photons leaving the Sun must be many times that of neutrinos leaving the Sun. And assuming isotropic (uniform) distribution of solar radiation, the number of solar photons reaching Earth must far outnumber the number of solar neutrinos reaching Earth.